# Increased the PHP.ini memory Limit without any affect

Tags: php, centos6

I got a centos server and updated the `/etc/php.ini` to 1024M and restart httpd. But my script is still showing:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

I have verified it with `phpinfo.php` and server is showing 1024M and I double checked the script if there is any `htaccess` or `ini_get('memory_limit')` but found nothing.

Comment: Rather than putting bandaids on, why not fix the problem? 1 GB is almost always an absurdly large amount of RAM for a PHP script to need.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
phpinfo();
die;
```

at the top of your script
You may have a local `.htaccess` file re-adjusting your memory limits.

Search for any `.htaccess` files in your scripts, or parent's directories and adjust there until your info returns expected values.